# JetBrains Gateway getting code 403 on remote download

Tags: jetbrains-ide

I'm trying to use JetBrains Gateway to set a development environment on a container, but it cant download the IDE Backend on remote.

[image]

Here is the log:

```
2022-01-25 11:11:54,740 [ 135972]  ERROR - creen.MultistagePanelContainer - JetBrains Gateway 2021.3 EAP  Build #GW-213.4958 
2022-01-25 11:11:54,741 [ 135973]  ERROR - creen.MultistagePanelContainer - JDK: 11.0.12; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o. 
2022-01-25 11:11:54,741 [ 135973]  ERROR - creen.MultistagePanelContainer - OS: Windows 10 
2022-01-25 11:11:54,741 [ 135973]  ERROR - creen.MultistagePanelContainer - Last Action:  
2022-01-25 11:11:54,743 [ 135975]   INFO - ains.gateway.ssh.SshDeployView - Wizard is done. Starting SSH deployment flow 
2022-01-25 11:11:54,766 [ 135998]   INFO - h.SshGatewayConnectionProvider - Trying to apply, parameters["type"] == ssh 
2022-01-25 11:11:54,770 [ 136002]   INFO -                         STDOUT - Info  | RdCoroutineScope          | 21:AWT-EventQueue-0 | RdCoroutineHost overridden  
2022-01-25 11:11:54,771 [ 136003]   INFO - h.SshGatewayConnectionProvider - Trying to connect 
2022-01-25 11:11:54,784 [ 136016]   INFO - .gateway.ssh.SshDeployFlowUtil - Deploy cycle started 
2022-01-25 11:11:54,795 [ 136027]   INFO - .gateway.ssh.SshDeployFlowUtil - Detected build number=213.4958 via downloadMethod=DefaultLink 
2022-01-25 11:11:54,795 [ 136027]   INFO - .gateway.ssh.SshDeployFlowUtil - Detected product=ideaIU 
2022-01-25 11:11:54,804 [ 136036]   INFO - .gateway.ssh.SshDeployFlowUtil - Remote projectPath= 
2022-01-25 11:11:54,839 [ 136071]   INFO - .gateway.ssh.SshDeployFlowUtil - In coroutine 
2022-01-25 11:11:54,956 [ 136188]   INFO - ateway.ssh.RemoteCredentialsEx - execCmd for 'uname' exited normally with exit code '0' 
2022-01-25 11:11:54,956 [ 136188]   INFO - ateway.ssh.RemoteCredentialsEx - Output of 'uname' command: "Linux" 
2022-01-25 11:11:55,064 [ 136296]   INFO - ateway.ssh.RemoteCredentialsEx - execCmd for 'echo ~' exited normally with exit code '0' 
2022-01-25 11:11:55,097 [ 136329]   WARN - om.intellij.ssh.impl.sshj.sshj - File /root/.CwmHost-IU-system/remote-dev-projects/active: No such file 
2022-01-25 11:11:55,100 [ 136332]   WARN - y.ssh.LinuxSshCommandsExecutor - File /root/.CwmHost-IU-system/remote-dev-projects/active: No such file 
2022-01-25 11:11:55,110 [ 136342]   INFO - .gateway.ssh.SshDeployFlowUtil - Starting remote host deployment 
2022-01-25 11:11:55,220 [ 136452]   WARN - ateway.ssh.RemoteCredentialsEx - execCmd for 'test -f '/root/.local/share/JetBrains/CwmHost/IU-213.4958/.expandSucceeded'' exited with non-zero exit code '1' 
2022-01-25 11:11:55,220 [ 136452]   WARN - ateway.ssh.RemoteCredentialsEx - Command output for 'test -f '/root/.local/share/JetBrains/CwmHost/IU-213.4958/.expandSucceeded'': "" 
2022-01-25 11:11:55,221 [ 136453]   WARN - ateway.ssh.RemoteCredentialsEx - Stderr for 'test -f '/root/.local/share/JetBrains/CwmHost/IU-213.4958/.expandSucceeded'': "" 
2022-01-25 11:11:55,225 [ 136457]   INFO - .gateway.ssh.SshDeployFlowUtil - Remote IDE Backend not found. Going to download and expand 
2022-01-25 11:11:55,234 [ 136466]   INFO - der.CodeWithMeClientDownloader - Downloading Thin Client jdk-build.txt 
2022-01-25 11:11:55,344 [ 136576]   INFO - ateway.ssh.RemoteCredentialsEx - execCmd for 'LC_ALL=C df -kP "/root"' exited normally with exit code '0' 
2022-01-25 11:11:55,453 [ 136685]   INFO - ateway.ssh.RemoteCredentialsEx - execCmd for 'mkdir -p '/root/.local/share/JetBrains/CwmHost/IU-213.4958'' exited normally with exit code '0' 
2022-01-25 11:11:55,562 [ 136794]   INFO - ateway.ssh.RemoteCredentialsEx - execCmd for 'command -v curl' exited normally with exit code '0' 
2022-01-25 11:11:55,671 [ 136903]   INFO - ateway.ssh.RemoteCredentialsEx - execCmd for 'command -v tar' exited normally with exit code '0' 
2022-01-25 11:11:57,098 [ 138330]   INFO - ateway.ssh.RemoteCredentialsEx - execCmd for 'LC_ALL=C curl -sIL 'https://cache-redirector.jetbrains.com/download.jetbrains.com/idea/code-with-me/remote-dev/ideaIU-213.4958.tar.gz'' exited normally with exit code '0' 
2022-01-25 11:11:57,100 [ 138332]   INFO - ateway.ssh.RemoteCredentialsEx - Downloading https://cache-redirector.jetbrains.com/download.jetbrains.com/idea/code-with-me/remote-dev/ideaIU-213.4958.tar.gz on localhost 
2022-01-25 11:11:57,102 [ 138334]   INFO - ateway.ssh.RemoteCredentialsEx - Trying to download https://cache-redirector.jetbrains.com/download.jetbrains.com/idea/code-with-me/remote-dev/ideaIU-213.4958.tar.gz once on localhost 
2022-01-25 11:13:25,569 [ 226801]   INFO - ateway.ssh.RemoteCredentialsEx - execCmd for 'curl -fSsL --output '/root/.local/share/JetBrains/CwmHost/IU-213.4958.tar.gz' 'https://cache-redirector.jetbrains.com/download.jetbrains.com/idea/code-with-me/remote-dev/ideaIU-213.4958.tar.gz'' exited normally with exit code '0' 
2022-01-25 11:13:25,583 [ 226815]  ERROR - h.SshGatewayConnectionProvider - Request failed with status code 403 
com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests$HttpStatusException: Request failed with status code 403. Status=403, Url=https://cache-redirector.jetbrains.com/download.jetbrains.com/idea/code-with-me/CodeWithMeGuest-213.4958-jdk-build.txt
```

Comment: this thing is not in Beta, it's in Alpha. Same problem for me.